# Combine JS function mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to combine JS functions, but that's not working. Does someone have a suggestion for my code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".searchs").keyup(function() {
    var searchbox = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox;
    if(searchbox=='') {
      $("#display").hide();
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "searchs.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          $("#display").html(html).show();
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
  $(".searchs").focus(function(){
    var seachbox = $(searchbox).val();
    if(seachbox != '') {
      $("#display").show();
    }
  });
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if ($("#display").is(":visible") && $(e.target).parents$("#display").length == 0) {
    $("#display").hide();
  }
});
```

For reference, I got that script from http://jsfiddle.net/bqQqN/15/. What I want to do is to add the mouseup function to my code. Anyone?

Comment: You are building up this through 7 questions. Now, I am wondering what you really have tried

Comment: As I see *it is* in your code. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to combine the two (though actions will be the same) you could

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
// ... whatever is already here
    }).mouseup(function(e) {
      if ($("#display").is(":visible") && $(e.target).parents$("#display").length == 0) {
        $("#display").hide();
      }
    });
```

Comment: if it doesn't work that meant that at the moment these object does not exist or selectors are wrong. Try debugging in mouseup(function(e) { debugger;